# getChildRoutes dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In react-router examples, have following code for dynamic load children, but I want to dynamic calculate the dependencies. However, it seems NOT work. `forEach` loop will throw error, says `"Cannot find module xxx"`

```
getChildRoutes(location, callback) {
    require.ensure([], function (require) {
      callback(null, [
        require('./routes/Announcements'),
        require('./routes/Assignments')
      ])
    })
  },
```

----###############################################----

```
getChildRoutes(location, callback) {
  require.ensure([], function (require) {
  var appsRoutes = ['routes/Announcements', 'routes/Assignments'].forEach(item=>{
    return require('./' + item);
  });
          callback(null, appRoutes)
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following variation work?

```
const dynamicRoutes = [
 './routes/Announcements', 
 './routes/Assignments'
];

...

getChildRoutes(location, callback) {
  require.ensure(dynamicRoutes, function (require) {
    var appsRoutes = dynamicRoutes.map(item => require(item));
    callback(null, appRoutes); 
  });
},
```

I think webpack needs to be able to calculate which modules to create dynamic hooks on to during compile time, which it isn't able to resolve due to your concat forEach loop approach.

This alternative could possibly work too:

```
 getChildRoutes(location, callback) {
   require.ensure([], function (require) {
     var appsRoutes = [
       require('./routes/Announcements'),
       require('./routes/Assignments')
     ];
     callback(null, appRoutes);
   });
 },
```

Read here for more info: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: It seems not work.  When compile, webpack will throw a warning: "the request of a dependency is an expression". When run it, webpack will throw error "can't find module"

Comment: For the alternative option too?

Comment: in fact, the appRoutes is calculated dynamic, something like var config = ['Annoucements', 'Assignments']; appRoutes = config.map(item=>{return './routes/' + item})

Comment: Do you mean that the `config` array (i.e. `var config = ['Announcements', 'Assignments']`) is mutated at run time? So you could for example during another route resolution have a variable of `var config = ['Announcements', 'Assignments', 'Foo'])`.  i.e. values get appended/removed from the array during run time?

Comment: <code>config</code>is not mutated. But <code>appRoutes</code> is calculated by <code>config</code>.

Comment: Ok, and did my second example not work?  I'll have to play around with this myself if not...

Comment: second example can work. But I mean appRoutes value can't declare directly. something like `['a', 'b'].forEach(item=>require('./' + item))`